# TCameraComponent fails under Android 12

Tags: delphi, android-camera, android-11, android-12

I have a Lenovo Tab M10, that I use for development with Delphi 10.4. A few days ago, a customer with the same tablet called to inform that the application "simply exits" without any message after updating to Android 12. My tablet also upgraded, so I'm experiencing the same behavior. The app just captures some data and, at a certain point, activates the camera for taking some pictures. This is where the trouble begins. It is important to focus two issues:

1. Nothing has changed in the code
2. The app is idle when taking the pictures. It's just waiting for the
   *TCameraComponent.OnSampleBuffer* to occur, which simply consists of:

```
procedure TfrmMain.camMainSampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
   const ATime: TMediaTime);   
begin   
  camMain.SampleBufferToBitmap(imgBuffer.Bitmap,True)  
end;
```

Here `imgBuffer` is just a `TImage` for displaying the image

Now, the problem is that the app display a few images (about ten) and then, indeed quits, or better stated, it generates an exception

> servicio.exe raised exception class 6 with message ''

This exception seems non-catchable, since any *Try/Except* block won't work.
I put a label on the screen to show how many, since as I stated, I cannot debug: the program is launched under D10.4, but any breakpoints are ignored.

```
procedure TfrmMain.camMainSampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
  const ATime: TMediaTime);   
begin   
  lbl1.text :=                  IntToStr(FCOUNTER);  
  Inc(FCOUNTER);  
end;
```

My first guess was that "something" changed in the `TCameraComponent` but later I found two very strange behaviors:

1. If I empty the event handler:

   ```
    procedure TfrmMain.camMainSampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject;
      const ATime: TMediaTime);   
    begin   
    end;
   ```

   The error (exception) still occurs.
2. If I do not assign the event handler, that is, leave it blank in the form designer the app runs fine (but of course, does not show any image)

As stated, the app is idle when the camera becomes active.

I have thought three possible solutions

1. Reflash the tablet to Android 11. My favorite but have no idea how
   to do it. We will be able to debug again
2. Add another SDK to Delphi 10.4. Maybe the app must be
   compiled for Android 12? Not quite sure how to do these nor it will fix the problem
3. Must upgrade Delphi?

I'm sorry I can't provide any more details, since I have found none, and I'm very confused. Any ideas how to fix this?

`Edit`: It was discovered that enabling both GPS and camera at the same time causes the bug. The GPS component is in a datamodule that provide some other methods. The camera component is in the main form. The code activates the GPS by calling a method, then `CameraComponent.Active := True`. After that the app crashes